# Oracle error message input value not long enough

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help with the below query. I am getting an error message :

> **ERROR:** Error fetching from cursor. ***ORACLE*** error is ***ORA-01840***: *input
>   value not long enough for date format.*

What input value is this referring to not being in date format? I can't figure this out. I do see where it refers to `AND Removed>= TO_DATE('08162011', 'MMDDYYYY')`.

```
    Removed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Probably you have a value like `TO_DATE('0816', 'MMDDYYYY')` for
  `TR_EFF_DT` input, and that does not fit with respect to the date
  format, as in the following statement :

  ```
  with tab(TR_EFF_DT) as
  (
   select TO_DATE('0816', 'MMDDYYYY') from dual   
  )
  select *
    from tab
   where TR_EFF_DT>= TO_DATE('08162011', 'MMDDYYYY');

  Error:
  ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
  ```
- ***OR*** you probably have a mismatch for your DB server's *Date Format* with your current session's *Date Format*. In this case you
  may issue :

  ```
  ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='MMDDYYYY';
  ```